# Android: dynamic key-names R.string

Tags: android

i have a strings.xml file:

```
<string name="wind_direction_n">North</string>
<string name="wind_direction_nne">North-Northeast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_ne">Northeast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_ene">East-Northeast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_e">East</string>
<string name="wind_direction_ese">East-Southeast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_se">Southeast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_sse">South-Souteast</string>
<string name="wind_direction_s">South</string>
<string name="wind_direction_ssw">South-Southwest</string>
<string name="wind_direction_sw">Southwest</string>
<string name="wind_direction_wsw">West-Southwest</string>
<string name="wind_direction_w">West</string>
<string name="wind_direction_wnw">West-Norhwest</string>
<string name="wind_direction_nw">Northwest</string>
<string name="wind_direction_nnw">North-Northwest</string>
```

And i need something like this:

```
String direction = "nn";
String message = R.string["wind_direction" + direction]
```

How can i do this?

Freddy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it accessing to runtime generated resources by name:

```
String direction = "nn";
String fullName = "wind_direction" + direction;

// Get the identifier of the resource by its name.
@StringRes int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fullName, "string", getPackageName());
// Use the value of the resource.
String message = getString(resId);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there also the opposite? Meaning from `R.string.some_string` to "some_string" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper `getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string.some_string)` should work!

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli Oh didn't know it exists. Thank you! Do you know perhaps if there is a way to list all of the resources of the app, too?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't know if there's an "official" way to do that. You can achieve that result with reflection on the R class though (but you should do it for every gradle module)

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli How would you know where to look for this class, and if it's indeed a valid one to look at?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Since you need just to list to the resources of the app, you can access with reflection `your.app.base.package.R` and read its content (there will be other classes inside like `string`).

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli So given some APK file, how can I do it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper oh maybe I understood wrong before. I thought you wanted to list all the resources of YOUR application, not of another external APK file. I don't know how to do it on another apk